# Cannot see log.LogInformation() messages in local storage

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have written a durable functions app and I am running/debugging it locally. My `local.settings.json` is:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

`host.json` is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "always",
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Information",
            "Function": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing in an ILogger to my function and it uses `log.LogInformation("...")`.

Using Azure Storage Explorer I can see an `AzureWebJobsHostLogs201901` table and it contains everything EXCEPT my log statements. I've exhausted Google searches and Microsoft Docs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking in the `<DefaultTempDirectory>\LogFiles\Application\Functions` folder? Kindly see the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#viewing-log-files-locally). Let us know if that's not working for you and we can investigate.